# Django and filtering encrypted fields

Tags: python, django, encryption, django-filter

I am using django-encrypted-fields to encrypt the data on my database. But I want to be able to filter them according to user's criteria e.g search a client with specific name (search term). But as I have read here and everywhere, you can't filter if you use EncryptedFields. So I was wondering is it ok to use standard for loops to iter on every db record and see if search term matches the fields of your model?

eg

```
clients = Client.objects.all()
post_data = form.cleaned_data

search_result = []
for client in clients:
    if (post_data['charfield1'].lower() in client.charfield1.lower() and 
        post_data['charfield2'].lower() in client.charfiedl2.lower() and...etc

        search_result.append(client)
```

I know it not efficient at all. But is there another way if you really want to be able to add filtering? And this method won't deal with None values (if you permit them) because you cannot do `post_data['field'] in customer.field` if customer.field is None. So this is a situation that I suppose need some compromising correct? How would you deal with it?

Comment: what's the reason `EncryptedFields` can't be queried?

Comment: no the cannot be filtered like Client.objects.all().filter(field1__icontains-searchterm)

Comment: Oh so you're talking about substring searching. I'm afraid you wont be able to do a substring searching in any way - that's the point of encryption.

Comment: yes...but when I do client.field1 it returns unecrypted value of field. So I guess you mean there isn't another way except for that I described in my post?

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 1.7 if you're using Postgres you can filter on encrypted fields using this package: http://django-pgcrypto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: But documentation says performance will drop with size of table because field cannot be indexed. Is there a better option to do this?